# Class to control two classes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have almost identical classes, `PaddleLeft` and `PaddleRight`. I am tired of calling both of those classes when I need something done, I rather them be done all at once. For example, here is what I have to do:

```
public void pause() {
    GameObject.Find("Paddle Objects/paddleRight").GetComponent<Paddle>().setIsPaused(true);
    GameObject.Find("Paddle Objects/paddleLeft").GetComponent<Paddle>().setIsPaused(true);
}
```

And here is what I want to do:

```
public void pause() {
    GameObject.Find("Paddle Objects/paddles").GetComponent<Paddle>().setIsPaused(true);
}
```

This seems unnecessary, however, in my game, there are times where the same line of code are copied and adjusted to up to ten similar objects.

Is there a way to make a super class like in Java for these objects. I don't understand how to make it work because I can't extend MonoBehavior and a superclass in Unity.

Comment: Have the super class (base class) derive from MonoBehaviour and then derive from that class.

Comment: Hi Luke.  Setting aside the total confusion in the question as pointed out by everyone, in a sense this is probably what you are looking for: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html  In some cases it can help you find "all" of a certain "thing".  But don't do this, do what Programmer says below.

Comment: I also suggest you read this essay http://stackoverflow.com/a/37243035/294884

Comment: Consider this thought exercise: there could well be ***other*** components on the game objects in question which ***set the pause in some different way***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have almost identical classes, PaddleLeft and PaddleRight

But your code is totally saying different stuff

```
 GameObject.Find("Paddle Objects/paddleRight").GetComponent<Paddle>().setIsPaused(true);
 GameObject.Find("Paddle Objects/paddleLeft").GetComponent<Paddle>().setIsPaused(true);
```

Maybe you want meant to write the code below?

```
 GameObject.Find("Paddle Objects/paddleRight").GetComponent<PaddleRight>().setIsPaused(true);
 GameObject.Find("Paddle Objects/paddleLeft").GetComponent<PaddleLeft>().setIsPaused(true);
```

I will assume the second code is what you meant to write.

When you have multiple **GameObjects** or Scripts with similar actions, you should create a central manager script that will make it easy to communicate with a those GameObjects or classes.

Since both your classes are called `PaddleRight` and `PaddleLeft`, You can simply call this class `PaddleManager`.

Don't forget that, of course, `PaddleManager` is just a script, it's not a "thing" in Unity.  Naturally you will attach `PaddleManager` to some game object. You might ask "where should I attach it?" In a simple game, you might attach it to your camera, say.  (Since you always have a camera, other developers working on your project always know to "look n the camera" for odds and ends like sound-effects, managers like this and so on.)  Alternately, say that physically all your paddles are associated with (for example) an object that is the ping pong table.  Then, a good place to attach `PaddleManager.cs` would be on the ping pong table.  It doesn't matter where you attach it, so long as it is tidy.  Some people like to make simply an empty object (you can refer to an empty object as a "marker"), just make an empty object named say "manager holder", put it at 0,0,0, and you can add scripts like `PaddleManager.cs` to that object.

Your `PaddleManager.cs` script:

```
public class PaddleManager : MonoBehaviour
{
   private PaddleRight rightPaddle = null;
   private PaddleLeft  leftPaddle = null;

    //Initialize variables
    void Start()
    {
        //Get reference/Cache
        rightPaddle =  GameObject.Find("Paddle Objects/paddleRight").GetComponent<PaddleRight>();

        //Get reference/Cache
        leftPaddle =  GameObject.Find("Paddle Objects/paddleLeft").GetComponent<PaddleLeft>();
    }

    //Call to pause and unpause
    public void pause(bool pausePaddle)
    {
        rightPaddle.setIsPaused(pausePaddle);
        leftPaddle.setIsPaused(pausePaddle);
    }
}
```

Now, you can access both of your Paddles from one script, in another script.

```
public class YourOtherScript : MonoBehaviour{

    PaddleManager paddleManager = null;

    void Start()
     {
         //Get reference/Cache
         paddleManager = GameObject.Find("GameObjectPaddleManaerIsAttchedTo") .GetComponent<PaddleManager>();

         //To pause
         paddleManager.pause(true);

         //To un-pause
         paddleManager.pause(false);
     }
}
```

By doing this, you will avoid using **static variable** and also avoid using `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("paddles"))` in `foreach` loop like mentioned in the other answer. `GameObject.Find...` functions should **NOT** be used in the middle of the game because it will **slow down** your game. You need to use it once and cache the **GameObject** in the `Start` function, then you can re-use it without slowing down your game.

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks Joe. He's been using `GameObject.Find("...")` where is not supposed to in all of his questions. Maybe he will understand what caching is this time.

Comment: I see, it's a "multi-question problem"  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow yup, it is. I have a question for you. I just realized that when you reach 200 in a day, your score won't go up until the next day. Have this ever happened to you?

Comment: unfortunately I do not know about that one.  Fascinating and bizarre.

Comment: @Programmer did you actually? Yea daily maximum is 200 points and you're gonna get a badge for that! nice!

Comment: @NikaKasradze I just googled this and realized it is true. Any up-votes are now discarded on my account except for accepted answers and bounties. Anyways, please listen to JoeBow, don't use statics. There maybe be few exceptions but the solution to this question is not one of them. The thing is static variables are still there between scenes. Look at the example of static gone wrong here http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/180515/applicationloadlevel-not-resetting.html For new users, it is even worst and introduces many new problems.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding one paragraph ("Don't forget that...") in the middle; feel free to roll back, edit etc

Comment: i did not know that @Nike (200 pts).  Good one Programmer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all paddle right and left are game-objects and not classes , the class name is paddle , and if the same script is on both the objects , the most simplest way would be to put it on another empty object and call it once and the code will work on all game-objects that the script is attached to . BUT! that is only regarding to what I cuold make out of your question , Here is what I really recommend , as you said "because I can't extend Mono-behavior and a super-class in Unity" . Ok so you have class A inheriting monobehavior , and you make class's B and C, then when you inherit them from A you will get all the abilities of a monobehaviour in class B and C and you can attach them to game objects , you can even make start and update functions as vrtual and override them in B and C and you can even call A's function use the keyword Base , So read on it , it will take time but in the long run makes you a better coder

Answer (score 0):

Mm, wait. There is something wrong with your question:

You`PaddleLeft` and `PaddleRight` are not classes. They are GameObjects existing in Unity scene. Class is `Paddle` to which you get reference by `GetComponent<Paddle>()` .

Now if you have a variable/function that affects all the instances of the class the same than you shell make them `static`. (Google static variables and functions if you don't know what they are).

So go to your `Puddle` class and change the declaration of `setIsPaused(bool val)` to this:

```
public static void setIsPaused(bool val) { /* implemenetation */ }
```

and then make a call to it via class token, not object:

```
Paddle.setIsPaused(true/false);
```

note that if the static function has references to class variables all those variables should be marked static as well. (e.g. if you have a `bool isPaused` than mark it static because it should be the same for all the objects all the time anyways)

Comment: the first two paragraphs here are very true.  while it is admirable to understand what a static is, **don't use statics** in Unity.  Nika, it's inconceivable a beginner like the OP (who does *not even know what a GameObject is*) should dabble with statics.  No Unity developer would solve the problem at hand with statics.  So, don't do this.

Comment: This QA exhibits a further **huge confusion with Unity**.  Note that the OP is confusing a "GameObject" with a "Class".  **But even worse** ... everyone here is confusing a behavior (just ***one of many*** behaviors that you may ***attach to a GameObject in Unity***) with the "thing itself".

Comment: @JoeBlow I just blindly trust you because of your reputation all over the internet. But... but... Why is static wrong in this case?

Comment: Lol we're all in trouble then right man? :-) I would just say that, you know how in programming you often hear "don't use globals!"  You know what I mean?  (For sure, there are indeed some cases where experts SHOULD use globals.  But, "newb" programmers always reach for globals to do everything, so of course, we always say "don't use globals!")  I would just say in short that similarly - don't forget many hobbyists are *literally learning to program! (for the first time!) using Unity!* - you just "don't use statics". It's just slack and avoids the proper game-engine solution (see P'm'r below)

Comment: Note that in an EXPERT sense there are MANY reasons you should NOT use static (in Unity)!!  So don't do it!  They are *just behaviors*, the OO layer in Unity is ***merely something you put on top of the actual real structure of Unity which is instantiated objects***.  Unity could in the future change entirely to using (say) functional programming (or .. Lisp! or something!  heh!) as the crap that you write the behaviors with.  But that ***would not change Unity at all***.  That is ***just*** the crap layer on top of the "actual" ECS system.  ...

Comment: sure, the programming language we use for now (c#) is OO and has classes, etc.  that's fantastic.  but that's only the language you're using (for now) to write behaviors to sit on the game objects.  it's impossible to and you can't "push down" OO concepts on to an ECS system.  Cheers!

Comment: that escalated quickly :/ but all right, I get it. How about a singleton config object for puddles or something? I'm just trying to see how he could get away with one-liner no matter how many `Puddles` he has.

Comment: Oh never mind, I just actually read Programmer's answer, thanks

Comment: Hi @Nika, for sure - that's what Programmer has done. For clarity, OP also, please read the paragraph "Don't forget that..." which I added in to Programmer's answer.  For experts, it is commonplace to say something like "make a script..."; what they actually mean is of course make a script and attach it to something appropriate in an idiomatic manner experienced engineers would understand. This can lead to the overall confusion (such as here) where beginners think unity has Classes, Inheritance etc like an OO system. Unity has no such thing, it only has completely plain no-heirarchy "things".