# how to make a gameObject rotate around another gameObject in Unity in the rotating plane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I've two gameObjects, `sphereOne` and `sphereTwo` as the children of an empty gameObject `both`.

I've this C# code attached to a `sphereTwo`

```
private void Update() =>
    transform.RotateAround(sphereOne.transform.position, 
        new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 100 * Time.deltaTime);
```

This lets `sphereTwo` rotate around `sphereOne`.

When I rotate the parent gameObject `both`, it rotates only on that specific plane.

[image]

How do I dynamically update the transform position of the rotating sphere so that it lies on the same plane as the parent Object's rotation?

Comment: Set it's position vector to that of it's parent in regards to the correct plane?

Comment: the secret here is you have AN EMPTY GAME OBJECT (often called a "marker") which "holds" the things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difficulty with rotating child around parent axes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753519/difficulty-with-rotating-child-around-parent-axes)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second parameter in [`Transform.RotateAround()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) is the axis which determines the orientation of the plane on which `sphereTwo` rotates around `sphereOne`. Right now, you have this set to a static value of `new Vector3(0, 1, 0)`, basically the world's up vector.

To have the axis instead be based on the orientation of `sphereOne`, use its `Transform.up` vector instead - this will change based on the world-space rotation of `sphereOne`'s transform:

```
private void Update() 
{
    transform.RotateAround(sphereOne.transform.position, sphereOne.transform.up, 100*Time.deltaTime);
}
```

(You could probably alternatively use `both.transform.up`, depending on the situation.)

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: that's all true but the OP needs to learn how to stack up transforms so as to achieve stuff like this!