# Difficultly combining Interfaces, Abstract class, Delegates, Generics and Covariance

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, interface, covariance

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to some help it seems to be a bug with Unity's compiler as it doesn't happen outside of Unity. I am currently submitting a bug report and I'll try and find a work around.

---

I originally posted this to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/4qvuuk/difficult_question_involving_interfaces_abstract/) but I think I will need all the help I can get. Here is it copied over:

Not sure how it has come to this, but in order to maintain maximum extendability I have had to use all this techniques.
In short, this works

```
ICombatEffect<IEffectReturn> com = new TackleEffectBase(this);
```

but when I try this

```
ICombatEffect<IEffectReturn>[] EffectsArra = ICombatEffect<IEffectReturn>[]{new TackleEffectBase(this);}
```

or this

```
List< ICombatEffect<IEffectReturn>> EffectsList = new List< ICombatEffect<IEffectReturn>>{new TackleEffectBase(this)}
```

I get an ArrayTypeMismatchException.

Now for the details: (although I've condensed this a lot)
p

```
ublic interface ICombatEffect<out T> where T : IEffectReturn
    {
        T Effect(CombatProcessor combat);
    }

public abstract class EffectTemplate<T1> : ICombatEffect<T1> where T1 : IEffectReturn
    {
        public abstract T1 Effect(CombatProcessor combat);
    }

public abstract class DamageBaseTemplate : EffectTemplate<DamageBaseModifier>
    {}

DamageBaseModifier : IEffectReturn

public class TackleEffectBase : DamageBaseTemplate
```

I've left out all of the functional stuff so I can let the types do the talking.
The premise is that I each ICombatEffect has an Effect Method. The Effect method must always have a return type that implements IEffectReturn interface. I need to preserve the return type of each ICombatEffect as it is used for sorting later.

Since I have quite a lot of functional code, I've put in the abstract class EffectTemplate. I've read a lot about this sort of style and the trick is to make the interface non-generic. I do not have that luxury unfortunately as sometimes I will not be using the template. So I have set up the interface with a covariant generic type. The abstract class sort of has its generic type linked so they will be the same. This took me a bloody long time to figure out and I was pretty disappointing when I couldn't get it to run today.

I'm no expert on generics but here is my theory on why I can create a single instance but not add that to a collection. When you declare the single instance it goes through and sets all the generics to the instance's type. For a collection, you can't really make its generics concrete, they are only there to see if it slots in.

I'm pretty ok with tearing this down for a better solution as long as it fulfills my needs, but I'm pretty darn curious about this solution. I thought myself so clever when I got all these cascading generic types to work, but alas.

Comment: The list line complies just fine. Same for array if you fix the syntax errors `ICombatEffect<IEffectReturn>[] EffectsArra = { new TackleEffectBase(this) };`

Comment: It compiles for me too, but whenever I try to add something to the array I get an error. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: You cannot "add" to array. But you can add to list and it works for me. I think you should edit your question and provide [mcve].

Comment: This is very bizarre on many levels.

Comment: FTR I would encourage you to read this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/38145855/294884

Comment: Thanks Joe but I don't understand how this relates to what we are discussing here, I must have missed something. I'm not dealing with game objects at all. If you are referring to a component based design opposed to inheritance, don't worry that is one of my main focuses.